hardware GPU-assisted video DECODE and ENCODE with Intel NUC avail GPUs?
I’m asking for help on choosing a newer Intel NUC (I have NUC 8i5 from 2020), specifically to do 4K video processing using OpenVINO and OpenCV in C++ under Ubuntu 22.04 LTS 64-bit in headless configuration.
Considering the NUC 9i7 (6-core), and my question is which GPU to get with it?
I see various NUC models with i7 CPU, with choices for Graphics CoProcessor, such as
* Intel® UHD Graphics
* Intel® Iris® Xe Graphics
* or even external Intel® Arc™ GPU Series. I see some NUCs support extra GPU card.
Specifically, I am wanting to use hardware-assisted GPU for frame decoding the incoming 4K RTSP stream in H.264 (maybe H.265)… and then, using OpenCV processing frame-by-frame… write the finished frame of 4K video to hard drive using hardware-assisted H.264 or H.265 video encoding and save it as .mp4 file.
This all works fine with my older NUC 8i5, but it only supports hardware VIDEO DECODE on incoming frames (which is good), but no hardware-assisted VIDEO ENCODE on output, so the CPU has to do it, and I’m limited to something like 12 fps, and only at 1920x1080 resolutions.
I’m looking to upgrade so I can get full use of newer GPU to output true 4K at 3840x2160 resolution, at whatever reasonable frame rates I can get… and 24 fps would be great.
How to know which GPU choice is going to work with OpenVINO 2023.3 (LTS) and would these newer GPUs provide my hardware-assisted video DECODE and video ENCODE accessed via OpenCV within OpenVINO?
